# Javascript Get Function By Pointer

Tags: javascript, function-pointers

**Quick question:** How do I get a pointer to a *pre-declared* function in javascript.

Say in my .js file I have

```
function a() {
    var bref = `a pointer/ref to b() here`
}

function b(param) {
    ...
}
```

I want `bref` to be simply a pointer to the function `b` and not just the result of a call to `b()`

**Edit:** Forgot to mention: function `b` takes in one parameter i.e `b(param)`

Have tried `bref = b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply:

```
function a() {
    var bref = b;
    ...
    x = bref("cake");
}

function b() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use the function name for assignment.

To call the function you can use

> [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

or

> [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

methods.

e.g:

```
function a() {
    var bref = b;
    .
    .
    b.call(null, "Something")
}

function b(src) {
    ...
  alert(src);
}
```

Working example @: http://jsfiddle.net/UasYH/1/

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, b takes a parameter. I tried doing: bref = b But it still has problems.